# anchorScroll on static page with Angular 7.x.x?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, anchor-scroll

I have a static page for terms&conditions.

Links are set up like this

```
<li>
    <a [routerLink]=""
    fragment="user-submission-testimonials">User Submission Testimonials</a>
</li>
```

terms-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: BasicLayout,
    children: [
      { path: 'terms-and-conditions', component: TermsAndConditionsComponent }
    ]
  }
];

const routerOptions: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: false,
  anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
  scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'
};
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, routerOptions)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class TermsRoutingModule { }
```

What manages the scroll "animation":

```
export class TermsAndConditionsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private element: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    console.log(this.element.nativeElement.id)
    this.route.fragment.subscribe((fragment: string): void => {
      if (fragment && this.element.nativeElement && this.element.nativeElement.id === fragment) {
        this.element.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I have console.log for debugging purposes, it prints out nothing not even undefined. It's just blank. However if i try to do this with regular JS like:

```
ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    this.route.fragment.subscribe((fragment: string): void => {
      if (fragment && document.getElementById(fragment) !== null) {
        document.getElementById(fragment).scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
```

Thou i am forbidden to use JS, it needs to be done with TS. Or at least my superior says that it's not TS and i need to do it with Angular related TS

I've seen a post [directive solution on reddit because of ElementRef XSS isues](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/9e93hc/scroll_to_anchor_fragment_not_working/e5qy2w5/)
But its not working for me :(
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Use [ViewportScroller](https://angular.io/api/common/ViewportScroller)

ViewportScroller is a Service which you can inject in the constructor. It provide diffrent types of method, Use scrollToAnchor method to achieve id based anchor scrolling.

**Try this:**

**component.html**

```
<li>
    <a [routerLink]=""
    fragment="'user-submission-testimonials'">User Submission Testimonials</a>
</li>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Location, ViewportScroller } from '@angular/common';
import { Router, Scroll, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';


export class TermsAndConditionsComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private router: Router, private viewportScroller: ViewportScroller) { }

  ngOnInit(){
   this.router.events.pipe(filter(e => e instanceof Scroll)).subscribe((e: any) => 
   { this.viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(e.anchor);  });

}}
```

Ref:https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2018/07/26/what-is-new-angular-6.1/

Comment: Thanks it's working however not reliable, it navigates to the terms route but not scrolling the required fragment to view all the times, and i don't know why :(

Comment: did you add id to that element?

Comment: I managed to reproduce my issue. It's not scrolling to a desired fragment when you first load the terms page. If it's been loaded once, it scrolls to it, and it's not scolling to the same fragment twice ([hostname]/terms#[fragment]) is already in the browser url

Comment: can you create stackbitz?

Comment: I have them set up like this:
`<h2 id="linking-to-the-website">Linking to the Website</h2>`
To this the link is the following:
` <a [routerLink]="" fragment="linking-to-the-website">Linking to the Website</a>`

If i want to access it from another source then:
`<a routerLink="/terms-and-conditions" fragment="linking-to-the-website">[whater i want to appear]</a>`

Comment: Check this stackbitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-scroller

Comment: I've done this by your first comment, however. As I mentioned it's not working 1st. After that it scrolls to the desired fragment.

Comment: Try to add the setTimeout

Comment: This is working perfect for me.